# Redirect Shared Folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

We've moved data from one shared folder to another shared folder on a different server.  People have access to old links in emails to the old folder location.  I can't change those links, so I'd like the links to go to the new folder location.

I'm not sure, but this might be different than "Folder Redirection" that keeps coming up whenever I Google this question  -- folder redirection seems to apply to user document folders.  I also tried creating a shortcut to the new location on the old server, but of course, that would be too easy, so there is no option to share a shortcut.

Comment: Is the old server still in use?

Comment: Yes, it looks like MCMarra had the same thing in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the old server isn't being used any more, you can make a DNS CNAME record with the old server's name and point it at the new server. If the old server is still being used, there's not a lot you can do.

In the future, you can obscure the paths of these shares by using a DFS Namespace. I suggest you look into deploying this while you're making these changes now, it will  make your life a lot easier down the line.

Comment: Ok, that's fine.  Just needed to know.  I'm not really the guy who sets up the servers, more of a software developer.  I'll take this into consideration in future development.